# right adjoint functor for closed immersion of topoi

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Let $i\colon (X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$ be a closed immersion of ringed topoi. Does functor $i_*\colon Mod(A)\rightarrow Mod(B)$ have a right adjoint?

Comment: The answer to the non-additive version of the question is no: for instance, the inclusion of a point in a $T_1$-space is a closed immersion, but the induced direct image functor (i.e. the skyscraper sheaf functor) on sheaves of sets doesn't have a right adjoint in general.

Comment: Isn't it enough to check that $i_*$ is cocontinuous?